# Create new dataframes for each unique value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a presence/absence dataframe that looks like this (it's much larger but have reduced it for this question):

```
annotations   factor1   factor2   factor3   Class
heroine       1         0         1         OPIOID_TYPE
he smokes     0         1         0         OTHER_DRUG_USE
heroin        1         0         1         OPIOID_TYPE
```

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe for each unique value in 'Class' and insert each value in class as the name of the last column for each dataframe and record presence/absence.

In other words:

```
annotations   factor1   factor2   factor3   OPIOID_TYPE
heroine       1         0         1         1
he smokes     0         1         0         0
heroin        1         0         1         1
```

and:

```
annotations   factor1   factor2   factor3   OTHER_DRUG_USE
heroine       1         0         1         0
he smokes     0         1         0         1
heroin        1         0         1         0
```

In reality, my dataframe is much larger with 2289 rows and 1273 columns and exactly 23 unique values in 'Class' for a total of 23 new dataframes.

I assume a loop structure would work here but I have limited experience with python looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your `Class` values:

```
dfs = {}
for klass in df['Class'].unique():
    dfs[klass] = df.assign(**{klass: df['Class'].eq(klass).astype(int)}) \
                   .drop(columns='Class')
```

Now you have a dict indexed by `Class` values:

```
>>> dfs.keys()
dict_keys(['OPIOID_TYPE', 'OTHER_DRUG_USE'])

>>> dfs['OPIOID_TYPE']
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OPIOID_TYPE
0     heroine        1        0        1            1
1   he smokes        0        1        0            0
2      heroin        1        0        1            1

>>> dfs['OTHER_DRUG_USE']
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OTHER_DRUG_USE
0     heroine        1        0        1               0
1   he smokes        0        1        0               1
2      heroin        1        0        1               0
```

### **The following is strongly discouraged**

Now if you really want real python variables, you can use `locals()` to create them dynamically:

```
for idx, klass in enumerate(df['Class'].unique(), 1):
    print(f"df{idx} is for '{klass}' class")
    locals()[f"df{idx}"] = df.assign(**{klass: df['Class'].eq(klass).astype(int)}) \
                             .drop(columns='Class')

# Output:
df1 is for 'OPIOID_TYPE' class
df2 is for 'OTHER_DRUG_USE' class
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OPIOID_TYPE
0     heroine        1        0        1            1
1   he smokes        0        1        0            0
2      heroin        1        0        1            1

>>> df2
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OTHER_DRUG_USE
0     heroine        1        0        1               0
1   he smokes        0        1        0               1
2      heroin        1        0        1               0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really sure what's going on in the second part but is there a way to extract each "dataframe" in the dict to a series of objects? i.e. df1 - df23?

Comment: The second part is what you want, create variables dynamically. I updated my answer based on your comment. Now you can use df1, df2, ..., df23 as independent dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `get_dummies` and save the dfs into `dict`

```
s = df.pop('Class').str.get_dummies()
d = {x : df.join(s[[x]]) for x in s}
```

Example output below

```
d['OPIOID_TYPE']
Out[43]: 
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OPIOID_TYPE
0     heroine        1        0        1            1
1    hesmokes        0        1        0            0
2      heroin        1        0        1            1
d['OTHER_DRUG_USE']
Out[44]: 
  annotations  factor1  factor2  factor3  OTHER_DRUG_USE
0     heroine        1        0        1               0
1    hesmokes        0        1        0               1
2      heroin        1        0        1               0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to extract each of these as separate dataframes from the dict?